# How to send files from PC to Android device programmatically

Tags: android, file-io

For my application i need to send a document from PC to Android device programmatically. I've searched along some forums, but couldn't find any sample for this.

Can any one help me with the sample code. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Smith

Comment: use bluetooth programming in your application,may be this link will help you,http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

Comment: You can use http or ftp client/server model to achieve file sharing with pc.

Comment: without using bluetooth i have to acheive it. And can you say how to use http or ftp client/server model with sample code?? Am very new to android, so strucking very much.l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a socket connection. the pc would be  your server and the android app would be your client.
This way you can send data (including documents i presume) from your mobile device to your pc and vice versa.

Comment: hi wottah, thanks for your response. Can you send me the sample code for this.

Comment: I suggest reading this tutorial to get more understanding of what sockets are and how they are implemented:
http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-1996/jw-12-sockets.html?page=1
 the code is written for java apps, but it can be used for writing android apps as well.