# sending a SMS from android phones to a computer?

Tags: android, sms

I am creating an android application which gets the phones location, Latitude and Longitude, and time and sends it to a central database at regular intervals. The problem is I am using SMS to send this data and I am having trouble figuring out where to send it. The first thing which came to my mind is a computer which stores all this data and reads it then carries out an action based on the data, in this case it maps it.

So is it possible to send a SMS to a computer? Or should I try out a different method to send the data?

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks! :)

***EDIT***

I understand it is possible to connect my phone to the computer and then transfer the SMSs but I actually just have 1 phone right now and I cant have it always hooked up to the computer.

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737067/how-to-send-files-from-pc-to-android-device-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Euhm SMS? I dont think that is possible.
Try to use JSON. 
https://www.google.nl/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Send+data+to+server+android+json

Answer (score 0):

You can connect you phone to your computer as SMS modem and get its SMS from your phone. Almost phone can do this. But the most common way is that integrated with a web service.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to send sms to a computer if that computer has a GSM module (or mobile phone connected as modem) you should rather consider a different method.

I'd go with sending emails or - if you are willing to - create an AppEngine Project to receive the data.